# Connecting External Hard Drive to Bluray Player

Tags: ntfs, blu-ray

Just a follow up, is there any way that I can connect 1TB external hard drive formatted in ntfs to samsung bluray bdp1600?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to hook up your blueray player to the external device so that you can use it as an external device, are are you trying to connect them both to the machine at the same time so that you can copy data back and forth?  we need a little bit more information to help you.

Answer (score 1):

No. According to the Samsung BD-P1600's [product specifications](http://www.samsung.com/us/consumer/tv-video/blu-ray/blu-ray-players/BD-P1600/XAA/index.idx?pagetype=prd_detail&tab=spec), it does not have any USB 2.0 ports, so you cannot connect an external HDD. Even it had a USB port, you would have to format the HDD in FAT32 format.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I need to correct the wrong info.  I still own a BD-P1600 and it in fact has 2 USB ports, one at the front and one in the rear.